# Popup not closing from parent when modal box is called

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with closing a pop window. My problem is unique in kind if I click Logout from the parent, it closes all the windows, but when I log out from a child, then I am logging out from Parent, so it does not close the other child windows that are open.

When I am logging out from a child and then I am logging out from a parent, I checked in console and it is not going inside the if block.

The only variation between when I am logging out from a child and parent window is if I logout from parent it will close all the window and redirect parent and if I logout from child first it will create modal dialog box on parent with message session time out.

When I am logging out from child I am getting an `Invalid Session Id passed` from server and then I am invoking function

```
showModalBoxForInvalidSessionInfo
```

In this when I am checking in console I am not get the awin and bwin variable value. They are setting to undefined. But if I call onLogout function directly it will get the actual value.

I am not able to understand what is the difference here why the value is not getting inside even when I am declaring it as a gloabal variable.

I am pasting my JS file for the refrence

```
var userName;
var sessionId;
var userName;
var userId;
var awin;
var bwin;
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            userName = getURLParameters('userName');
            sessionID = getURLParameters('requestID');
            userId = getURLParameters('userId');
            var welcomeMsg = document.getElementById('welcomeMsg');
            var text = document.createTextNode('Welcome ' + userName );
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.style.height = '16px';
            img.style.width = '16px';
            img.src = 'images/arrow.png';
            welcomeMsg.appendChild(text);
            welcomeMsg.appendChild(img);
            //style="width:16px; height:16px;"
            console.log("Ready");
            var fullAuthUrl = authorizationUrl
                    + "?requestType=getRoles&username=" + userId
                    + "&requestID=" + sessionID;
            console.log(fullAuthUrl);
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache : false
            });
            $.ajax({
                url : fullAuthUrl,
                dataType : 'text',
                crossOrigin : true,
                cache : false,
                type : 'GET',
                success : function(response) {
                    //console.log("Success");
                    var responseBodyFull = response.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                    //responseBodyFull = response;
                    if (responseBodyFull == "Invalid Session Id passed") {
                            console.log("Invalid Session");
                            showModalBoxForInvalidSessionInfo();
                           }
                    console.log(responseBodyFull);
                    enableOrDisableLinks(responseBodyFull);
                }
            });
        });
function b() {
    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    userName = getURLParameters('userName');
    userId = getURLParameters('userId');
    lvalue = getURLParameters('lValue');
    lver = getURLParameters('lVer');
    window.name = "parent";
    var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen 
        var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
        var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...

                   + ",location=no"      //URL field

                   + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...

                   + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.

                   + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.

                   + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.

                   + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.

                   + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.

                   + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788

                   + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               

                   + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.

                   + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.

                   + "";  
     bwin = window.open(bUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId
            + "&userId=" + userId,'_blank',strWinProp);
}

function a() {
    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    userName = getURLParameters('userName');
    userId = getURLParameters('userId');
    lvalue = getURLParameters('lValue');
    lver = getURLParameters('lVer');
    window.name = "parent";
    var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen 
        var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
        var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...

                   + ",location=no"      //URL field

                   + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...

                   + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.

                   + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.

                   + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.

                   + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.

                   + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.

                   + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788

                   + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               

                   + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.

                   + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.

                   + "";  
     awin = window.open(aUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId + "&userId="
            + userId,'_blank',strWinProp);
}

function showModalBoxForInvalidSessionInfo(){
    $("#modelView").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        buttons : [ {
            text : "OK",
            icons : {
                primary : "ui-icon-heart"
            },
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
    $("#modelView" ).dialog("open");
    $("#modelView").text("Session Timed Out");
}       
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       return new XMLHttpRequest(); //To support the browsers IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
       return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For the browsers IE6, IE5
       } else {
       alert("Error due to old verion of browser upgrade your browser");
           }
       }

function onLogout(){
 if (awin && !awin.closed) {
        awin.close();
        }
if (bwin && !bwin.closed) {
        bwin.close();
    }       
window.location = loginPageUrl;

}
```

HTML file is very simple having two buttons calling function a and function b and a menu from where function onLogout is called.

Somebody please help me on this.

Comment: When logging out from child you call opener.onLogout() ? And are awin and bwin in scope in that function when called from child? You also have an invalid space in `var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"` and a() and b() are idential. If you do 
`return  window.open(aUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId + "&userId="
            + userId,'_blank',strWinProp);` you can have one function

Comment: But then function will call both the window. I don't want that. See awin and bwin are two seperate windows they are valid value till I call  showModalBoxForInvalidSessionInfo after that I don't what is happening

Comment: What I mean is where you do a() and where you do b() you instead do `awin=openWin()` and `bwin=openWin()` assuming you rename a() to openWin and delete b(). Anyway I do not see what the issue is unless you change the content of the parent window before closing all child windows